# Linus virtualserver - multiple URLs and IP address

Tags: linux, virtualhost

I set up a Linux virtualhost on server with IP address 888.888.888.888 where

document root for URL site1.mysite.com is /var/www/content1 and
document root for URL site2.mysite.com is /var/www/content2.

The following directives work, however if user enters 888.888.888.888, I want to direct user to /var/www/content2.  I am not sure how to do this.

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>  
  ServerName site1.mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/content1
  ServerAlias www.site1.mysite.com  
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName site2.mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/content2
  ServerAlias www.site2.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: 888.888.888.888 is not a valid IP address.

Comment: Thank you. I was not meant literally, Assume I meant 4 numeric segments separated by dots, each segment between numeric 1 and 256 without right padding for zeros.

Comment: Please use example.com instead of mysite unless you really do own that domain. Also use [rfc5757](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5737) addressing for examples.

Answer (score 2):

In a name based virtual host system, if a `host` header is not presented or if a host header is presented but the host is not matched against a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` then the content of the default virtual host is served. The default virtual host is the first one that is defined in the configuration.

In your particular case this is `site1.example.com`. You can have the contents of `site2.example.com` served as the default by defining it before site1. You could also add a `*` catchall to site2's  ServerAlias. You would in that configuration have to ensure that site2 was configured last.